# How to take the current key from array? PHP

Tags: php

I want to take the current key in the array.
I know the function current($array) but it take the value.

Rules:

1. I cannot use in any loop.
2. Without array_flip().
3. I need function.. if you can mix the function current($array) it'll be great!

Thank you.

Comment: You say `I cannot use in any loop` , what do you mean by current then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like key() ?

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php